# Swift type conversions: Getting color data as CGFloat to an NSData of 8bit integers

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, cgfloat

*For posterity: this question is referencing iOS8 Beta 4*

I'm trying to get an `NSData` instance full of 24 bit colors. The bytes would be `[r,g,b, r,g,b, ...]` so 3 bytes per color, all tightly packed together.

Problem is that I need some `Uint8`s to use as bytes to fill that I derive from the `CGFloats` of `UIColor`. And Converting from `CGFloat` to `UInt8` is giving me a very hard time

> 'CGFloat' is not convertible to 'UInt8'

I've read this question: [‘CGFloat’ is not convertible to ‘UInt8' and other CGFloat issues with Swift and Xcode 6 beta 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873219/cgfloat-is-not-convertible-to-uint8-and-other-cgfloat-issues-with-swift-and)

Which is the same error message, but all I was abel to gather is that not all number values are convertibel between each other and I must use an intermediary type. But I'm not sure which.

```
let lightCount: Int = 48
var colors: [UIColor] // inited by appending "lightCount" UIColor instances

func dataBlob() -> NSData {
    var data = NSMutableData(capacity: lightCount*3)

    for i in 0..<lightCount {
        var r: CGFloat = 0
        var g: CGFloat = 0
        var b: CGFloat = 0

        colors[i].getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: nil)

        data.appendBytes([
            UInt8(r * 255.0),
            //    ^ ERROR: CGFloat is not convertible to UInt8

            UInt8(g * 255.0),
            UInt8(b * 255.0),
        ], length: 3);
    }

    return data
}
```

I've tried a bunch of combos for converting to some intermediary types like `Float` or `Int` to no avail.

And furthermore, is my approach here even sane? Is there a simpler way I've missed?

Comment: Never used Swift, but try `r * 255` instead of `r * 255.0`. Just a hunch.

Comment: You can convert r to a UInt 8 like this: `UInt8(r)`. It looks like your code may have other issues though

Comment: @duci9y Nope :( Pretty sure the computer chooses types for number literals pretty intelligently based on context. @connor Well `r` is a `CGFloat` of zero to one. I want that as an `UInt8` from zero to 255. `Uint8(r)` would only ever be zero or one.

Comment: Use `Double` instead of `CGFloat`?

Comment: @duci9y I can't change that `UIColor` returns it's color data as `CGFloat`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured this out, thanks some good questions asked by you dudes.  I had to convert to `Int` and I had to cast the array to `[Uint8]`.

```
        var bytes: [UInt8] = [
            UInt8(Int(r * 255.0)),
            UInt8(Int(g * 255.0)),
            UInt8(Int(b * 255.0))
        ]
        data.appendBytes(bytes, length: 3);
```

Or:

```
        data.appendBytes([
            UInt8(Int(r * 255.0)),
            UInt8(Int(g * 255.0)),
            UInt8(Int(b * 255.0))
        ] as [UInt8], length: 3);
        // ^ casted here
```

Seems the compiler really should have been able to figure this out though.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be working for me:

```
var arr = [
UInt8( Int( r * 255)),
UInt8( Int( g * 255)),
UInt8( Int( b * 255)),
]
data.appendBytes(arr, length: 3);
```

From what I can tell the types you can convert back and forth to CGFloat are Int, UInt, Float and Double. From those intermediary conversions you can convert to other types.

Answer (score 1):

This works in the beta4 playground:

```
let red : CGFloat = 0.5
let redByte = UInt8(Int(red * 255.0))
```