# SourceKitService has runaway memory leak when declaring array of ranges

Tags: xcode

Code:

```
let ranges = [100...200000, 2019212...3049577…] // and so on
```

Just as I finish typing the `]`, Xcode UI hangs. Activity Monitor reveals that `SourceKitService` suffered a runaway memory leak, going from 260 MB to 20 GB of memory in 5 seconds flat.

Is there a known fix for this bug? Or is it a new one that I discovered? If so, what could be possible fixes/workarounds?

I haven't been able to discover if this happens with small ranges or big ones, since I'm effectively locked out of Xcode right now.

Using Xcode 6.4 on OS X 10.10.4, writing for iOS 8.4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SourceKitService Consumes CPU and Grinds Xcode to a Halt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151954/sourcekitservice-consumes-cpu-and-grinds-xcode-to-a-halt)