# Xcode builds are taking much longer than usual and causing MacBook fans to go crazy

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sourcekitservice

I am building/running a relatively simple chat application. Every time I run/build the application, the fans on my MacBook get extremely loud and my computer begins to heat up very quickly. Furthermore the builds are taking a ridiculous amount of time to finish, even after editing just a single line of code.

I opened up activity monitor and noticed that "SourceKitService" was using 100% of the CPU.

Earlier today, I deleted the DerivedData folder for my project, and that still doesn't seem to solve this issue.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SourceKitService Consumes CPU and Grinds Xcode to a Halt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151954/sourcekitservice-consumes-cpu-and-grinds-xcode-to-a-halt)

Comment: I've tried everything that post suggested, but the issue still persists.

Comment: Start by following the steps here and let us see your spindump: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/412988/404917

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a deep clean (Command+Shift+K), deleting derived data, closing Xcode, and restart Mac. That usually helps me. However, when I'm running apps on my 8GB memory Mac some cause the same issue while my 16GB Mac runs them just fine.

Comment: I just tried this, but unfortunately the problem still persists