# "'CGFloat' is not convertible to 'UInt8'" - CGFloat wrapping issue

Tags: ios, swift, cgfloat

```
label.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width*0.125, self.size.height-CGFloat(0.15)*self.size.height*_activeEnemiesArray.count)
```

I get an error pointing to `self.size.width` that says

> 'CGFloat' is not convertible to 'Double'.

This makes sense, since a `CGFloat` value and a `Double` value cannot be multiplied, but then when I convert the `0.125` to `CGFloat`:

```
label.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width*CGFloat(0.125), self.size.height-0.15*self.size.height*_activeEnemiesArray.count)
```

I get an error pointing to `self.size.width` that says

> 'CGFloat' is not convertible to 'UInt8'

This does not make any sense. Has anyone else been experiencing this and what could be the cause?

Comment: possible duplicate of [‘CGFloat’ is not convertible to ‘UInt8' and other CGFloat issues with Swift and Xcode 6 beta 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873219/cgfloat-is-not-convertible-to-uint8-and-other-cgfloat-issues-with-swift-and)

Comment: Both of above are working for me, check it once again(i have tried it in playground)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode is leading you astray -- literals shouldn't really ever cause problems, as they'll get converted into `Double` or `CGFloat` as needed once everything else is the same type. Instead, what's going on is that you have an `Int` at the very end of your line:

```
... * self.size.height * _activeEnemiesArray.count)
```

That `count` property needs to be converted to `CGFloat` so it can be used with the rest:

```
... * self.size.height * CGFloat(_activeEnemiesArray.count))
```

Answer (score 1):

just try

```
self.frame.size.width
```